# Installing a Hive Thermostat

Tags: electrical, heating, thermostat

I purchased a HIVE thermostat and want some assurance before I go about installing this.

First of all i was wondering where to put the receiver as I thought it would just replace one of the thermostats however my thermostats only have 2 cables plugged into them so maybe needs to go somewhere else. Anyway I took my thermostat of the wall and the current cables show the following:

- A: Yellow / Green cable attached to nothing.
- B: Smaller Grey cable attached to nothing.
- C: Brown cable plugged into 2 COM on thermostat
- D: Grey cable plugged into 3N/0

The Hive reciever has the following:

- N: Permanent Neutral
- L: Permanent Live
- 1: Hot Water off (NC)
- 2: Heating off (NC)
- 3: Hot water on (NO)
- 4: Heating on (NO)

I have a combi boiler so dont really need to do the hot water part but am wondering if i can just put the reciever where the thermostat is for the zone i want to control or does it need to go near the boiler and then i connect directly from there.

Also if it does go in place of the old thermostat how do the cables go e.g. does the A -> N, B -> L, C -> 2, D -> 4? Or do I need to do it from the boiler / get someone in to do this?

Comment: Where on the planet are you?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel i'm in the UK

Comment: Doesn't the device come with instructions? When one was offered to me, it was with the presumption that I would also pay for professional installation, but I can't imagine it could be that complicated to necessarily require it. It could be that this is assumed in how it's packaged, or you've got the OEM version whereas a retail version would have instructions. Could you please specify?

Comment: Yeah basic instructions. I just bought a self install kit and assumed it would just be like changing a lightbulb. There are only about 4 cables but as 2 of them are not plugged into my current thermostat i'm not quite sure what they actually are. Even the ones that are plugged in are not labeled the same either.

Comment: VTC: Needs more information and seems to have been abandoned.

Answer (score 1):

Your existing thermostat is just a switch - COM is the same a Permanent Live on the Hive and N/O (Normally Open) is the same as 4: Heating on (NO) on the Hive.

Everything else on the Hive you should be able to ignore - except the Permanent Neutral that the Hive needs and your old thermostat doesn't; this might be a problem.

There is a good chance the unconnected Grey cable is neutral, but I would investigate the other end of the cable, or put an electrical tester on it first.  If it isn't connected to Neutral at the other end you should be able to fix that in the boiler

The Yellow/Green is earth and should be at least connected to the backbox (although this might not be possible!)

**CAREFUL THOUGH!!**  This is all mains voltage stuff; make sure you understand what you're doing!